# Alternative to .Contains in linQ and subqueries

Tags: vb.net, linq, subquery, contains

I'm having issues with **.Contains** method in linQ. It gives **dramatic results** :(
There are many threads but not in vb.net and I'm kind of lost

---

Let's say I have *2 datatables* in my dataset :

-*The first* keeps a TREE structure (could be seen as this) :

```
Category (.id="1")
  |- Genre a (.id="13")
  |- Genre b (.id="15")
  |- ...
  |- Genre n
```

-*The second* keeps the data (20.000 rows)

Every rows in the data is attached to one node in the tree (either to main category, or to a sub category (genre))
Simply, every rows has a .Genre_Id property with the correct Id

---

Querying a simple node is quite easy.
But I need to query my dataset to get "**all rows from the category, including all rows from it's subcategories**"

So far I was using this CODE :

```
dim lnQ = (From data In tblData _
             Where data.Genre_Id = "1" _
             OrElse (From genre In tblStructure _
                          Where genre.parent_Id = "1" _
                     Select genre.Id).Contains(data.Genre_Id) _
             Select data).ToList
```

---

It works but has very bad effects on big databases.

What would be a **proper fix to totally AVOID the .Contains() method in vb.net** ?
I need the fastest solution, since my databases will grow up to 50.000 rows in the future !

I have tryed join but can't get it to work properly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with your solution. Does it give you an error, wrong results, or is it just slow?

Comment: Speed! It takes about 20/30 seconds. Other queries on the same exact database take 0.0.100  !  The .Contains() is in cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a solution.
Regex :)

```
lnQ = (From data In tblData.AsEnumerable() _
            Where Regex.IsMatch(data.Genre_Id.ToString, strIds) _
      Select data)
```

Before I can use this query, I had to build a valid regex of course

```
dim subquery = (From genre In tblStructure _
                        Where genre.Id = "1" _
                        OrElse genre.parent_Id = "1" _
                Select genre.Id)
```

And then with a simple loop I can get :

```
strIds = "^(1|13|15|etc...)$"
```

This is just an exemple of course. This regex is build from the possible ID's the datarow as to match

Works perfectly and instantly.
Does exactly the same as the .Contains() method, but it's much faster.

Hope this can help someone !